# Insert from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a PHP/MySQL project I am currently working on and have become stuck on a complicated (or at least to me) Insert function.

3 tables that apply here are

**Client**
Fields that are relevant here are, clientpk (AI primary key) and clientscope.

**Templatedocs**
, Fields that are relevant are templatepk, doctype, doctitle, templatescope

**ClientDocs**
Fields that are relevant docpk, doctype, doctitle

What I want to do is have a code after I add a new record in client table that inserts records from the templatedocuments table into the clientdocuments table where client.clientscope = templatedocuments.templatescope, and I suspect it will be a foreach function.

I have only ever worked with insert queries that insert from one table to another, not where 3 tables are used.

If someone could give me a basic idea then I should be able to figure the rest out, thank you.

UPDATE: What I am struggling here is say ClientTable is Table A, TemplateDocuments is Table B and ClientDocuments is TableC.  I know how to insert records from table A to Table C when I am writing an insert function from within Table A.  However I do not know how to Insert from table B (which is an unrelated resources table essentially) data into table C, using current variables from table B.

To put it into context, Table B now has 147 different records in, only 50 of them will end up in each table C, because there are variations, it is the client.clientscope and templatedocuments.template scope that filters which are relevant records to insert.

Comment: Consider using a `after insert trigger`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join`s in the `insert.. select` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO clientdocuments (doctype, doctitle)
SELECT doctype, doctitle
FROM   templatedocuments t
JOIN   client c ON t.templatescope = c.clientscope
WHERE  client.clientpk = 123
```

Comment: yes that is making sense and is close, how would I combine that with a Foreach function?

Comment: Why would you want t a foreach function? just insert all the missing items in a single statement by changing the condition on `clientpk`.

Comment: ok so would this work? $sql = "INSERT INTO documents_doucments (companyfk, doctype, doctitle) values ('".$values["companypk"]."', doctype, templatename) FROM templates_documents WHERE global_companies.msscope = templates_documents.scope)";CustomQuery($sql);

Comment: Thank you, will let you know, didnt know you could use a FROM statement

Comment: @user3169979 wait a sec, misread that - you're missing the `select`: `INSERT INTO documents_doucments (companyfk, doctype, doctitle) SELECT '".$values["companypk"]."', doctype, templatename FROM templates_documents WHERE global_companies.msscope = templates_documents.scope)"`

Comment: Same error, and i did change it to add SELECT, just didnt update screenshot

Comment: there seems to be an odd number of ( or ) ?

Comment: @user3169979 arg, looks like there's a redundant ")" at the end.

Comment: Ok I have now changed to $sql = "INSERT INTO documents_doucments (companyfk, doctype, doctitle) SELECT ('".$values["companypk"]."', doctype, templatename) FROM templates_documents WHERE templates_document.scope = '".$values["msscope"]."'";CustomQuery($sql); and I am getting Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 0):

you can use trigger something link this on mysql side:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `databaseName`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trigger_TableName`$$

CREATE

TRIGGER `trigger_Templatedocs` AFTER UPDATE ON `Client` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.field <> OLD.field THEN
    INSERT INTO Templatedocs (fieldName, fieldName2) VALUES (NEW.field, NEW.field);
END IF;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

i m not sure it's work for you or not but you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done using `AFTER INSERT` trigger on `client` table; something like below

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger trg_insert_clientdocs
after insert on Client
for each row 
begin
INSERT INTO ClientDocs(doctype, doctitle)
select td.doctype, td.doctitle
from Templatedocs td
where td.templatescope = new.clientscope;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Above trigger code will insert record to `ClientDocs` table from `Templatedocs` table based on a match on `templatescope` column; where the value of `templatescope` column is same as newly inserted value in `Client` table `clientscope` column.